# How can I get sub value in nested json via KQL?

Tags: azure, kql, kusto-explorer, appinsights

I try to access nested json in the Kusto query via KQL.  But I realized that assignedTo and AssignedTo2 are empty.How can I get sub value in nested json via KQL ?

this is my Kusto query :

```js
requests
| extend prop= parse_json(customDimensions.data) 
| extend AssignedTo = prop.SYNSTA_SynchronizationStatus
| extend AssignedTo2=customDimensions["data"]["SYNSTA_SynchronizationStatus"]
| where  customDimensions['source']=="xxxx"
| project  AssignedTo , AssignedTo2
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ut I realized that assignedTo and AssignedTo2 are empty.

I want Fullname in customDimensions :

[image]

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Then used the below query(modified your code):

```
requests 
| extend prop= parse_json(customDimensions) 
| extend AssignedTo = prop.FullName
| project AssignedTo
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you can simply use the [`coalesce`() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/coalescefunction).

for example:

```
let default_value = 0;
print input = dynamic({"value1":7,"value2":13})
| project value3 = coalesce(input.value3, 0)
```

if you actually need to modify the `dynamic` object, you can try using the [`bag_set_key()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-set-key-function)