# azure application insights custom dimeptions parameter - calculate query

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, custom-dimensions

Is there a way i can use Azure application insights to construct a query that can use numeric paramters in custom dimetions and calculate total value across entries matching criteria?

for instance - say prop_userId in the example below is 101. in other entries the value might be different, say 9 or 58 or 102.

i would like to calculate total value by adding all those values - 101 + 9 + 58 + 102 - adding together values for all entries in the logs together. is something like this possible to construct in app insights portal or would i have to do this in code?

[image: azure app insights example]

Comment: You mean, summing the values  as in 101+9 (=110)  or concatenating them like '101,9,58'?

Comment: Peter, i mean summing up values to calculate the total sum. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> adding together values for all entries in the logs together. is something like this possible to construct in app insights portal or would i have to do this in code?

Yes, it is possible and I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

Taken values inside custom dimension using [parse_json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction) and aggregate functions(sum,avg) :

[image]

**Kql Query:**

```
requests 
| sort by timestamp asc
| extend prop= parse_json(customDimensions) 
| extend Value = prop.FunctionExecutionTimeMs
| summarize avrg= avg(todouble(Value)) , Total = sum(todouble(Value))
| project avrg, Total, per=(avrg/Total)*100
```

**Output:**

[image]

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75989355/how-can-i-get-sub-value-in-nested-json-via-kql/75993230#75993230) for further information on parse_json.

Comment: you are a true gentleman, thank you! i will test this and get back with the results.

Comment: @SPT i have not tested it yet so dont know if it helped or not. i am aware of the idea of marking an answer as accepted and will make sure to do so as soon as i get this checked on my side. thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not for exactly the functionality i was looking to deploy it for.