# Azure Monitor: arithmetic on metrics

Tags: azure, datadog, azure-monitoring

I can perform calculations or arithmetic to create metrics based on other metrics, as Datadog does ...

¿Does anyone know if this is feasible?

I'm trying to perform some arithmetic on Azure Metrics, as Datadog does. In this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73779912/does-azure-monitoring-support-derived-metrics) it's asked something similar, without any answer.

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to perform addition, multiplication, percentage on azure metrics?

Comment: yes, that is actually what I want to do ... like formulas or expressions over the metrics

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to perform some arithmetic on Azure Metrics as Datadog does.

No it is not possible what datadog does, but alternatively you can use in below ways:

You can check Metrics in Transaction section of application insights like below:

[image]

Then in logs section you can do arthematic operations using kql queries like below:

[image]

You can use sum(), [percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76634832/azure-application-insights-custom-dimeptions-parameter-calculate-query/76635174#76635174), This  way you can perform and create alerts too. You can use Azure Monitor too.

Comment: This is good for logs, as far I know ... but tou can't use KQL on metrics ...

Comment: Yeah, that is what i said that you can do on logs